# Vite throws error for electron app running on dev

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron, vite

I'm trying to convert my existing web app into a desktop app. While running the script for testing it on the dev server "npm run dev" I get the following error and the build fails.

`node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1360:21: ERROR: [plugin: vite:dep-pre-bundle] Missing "./jsx-runtime.js" specifier in "react" package`

I have previously tried to convert the react boilerplate code into an electron app and it worked fine. I also removed the node-modules, forced clean the cache and reinstalled all the packages again without any luck.